# link to publisher in google play not working

Tags: android, google-play

In my native android app i have a "more apps" button which I want to link to all my apps on google play.

I'm following this link: http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#UriSummary

As per the documentation in the link above, i used this query: market://search?q=pub:publisher_name. For publisher name i used my name without the brackets. BUT when i run the app and click on the "more apps" button, the google play store app opens and shows this message:

No results found for "pub:my_name_here"

If i remove the "pub" the url like this:market://search?q=publisher_name
then it shows all my apps. But the problem is that along with my apps, other apps are also being shown which match my surname. Not sure how to resolve this. All i want is to link to only my apps on google play.

I tried searching on Google, StackOverflow but did not find the solution. I tested this on Galaxy Note II. Not sure if it is a device specific issue. Has anyone come across something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this, I also had this issue and found that adding quotation marks around my developer name solved it.

Instead of this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:Liam Cottle"));
```

Change it to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:\"Liam Cottle\""));
```

The Google Play store app will only show results which match the quoted name exactly... Well, that's what I found anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue and the old link used to work up until now.

The workaround so far is to use

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/search?q=Vendor+Name"));

startActivity(marketIntent);
```

This works, but this is triggering the open with window and it also requires us to update every single app.

Edit: The provided answer by Liam does not work as this is the exact link and quotation we have been using for years, which just recently stopped working, the only working solution is using the web link above.